# Powershell - Where-Object in forEach Loop

Tags: powershell, powercli

I need some help for executing a little script and filtering results ...
I checkmy VM diskspace with the following script

```
Get-VM | ForEach-Object {
$VM = $_
$_.Guest.Disks | ForEach-Object {
$Report = "" | Select-Object -Property VM,Path,Capacity,FreeSpace,PercentageFreeSpace
$Report.VM = $VM.Name
$Report.Path = $_.Path 
$Report.Capacity = $_.Capacity
$Report.FreeSpace = $_.FreeSpace
if ($_.Capacity) {$Report.PercentageFreeSpace = [math]::Round(100*($_.FreeSpace/$_.Capacity))}
$report
 }
}
```

But I'd like to add a filter that my report only show me PercentageFreeSPace lesser than 20.

I try to add a where-object condition to my report with no success...

Can somebody help me please ? I m a beginner in PS...

Thanks in advance,
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

For future questions you should format your script to be more readable.

I believe I have done it quite well below:
[EDIT] Seems that something gone wrong with displaying your question on my laptop. Just after my answer, the formatting is almost the same as provided below.

```
Get-VM | ForEach-Object { 
 $VM = $_ 
 $_.Guest.Disks | ForEach-Object { 
      $Report = "" | Select-Object -Property VM,Path,Capacity,FreeSpace,PercentageFreeSpace $report 
      $Report.VM = $VM.Name 
      $Report.Path = $_.Path  
      $Report.Capacity = $_.Capacity 
      $Report.FreeSpace = $_.FreeSpace 
      if ($_.Capacity) {
           $Report.PercentageFreeSpace = [math]::Round(100*($_.FreeSpace/$_.Capacity))
      } 
      $report 
  } 
 }
```

To be honest I do not understand why you are using pipe at line 4.
Regarding your question, you should puy Where-Object clause **before** you will go to second for each loop.

Comment: Yep I think I was editing the format while you were answering me :)
To be honest I find this script here :https://code.vmware.com/forums/2530/vsphere-powercli#305281

I don't understand why should I put my Where-object before the second loop as I want to filter from this second loop ?

Sorry I m really noob ...

Comment: If I understand you correctly - you wanted to have report with disks below 20% of free space. You can reach that easily just after listing all disks.
This should also lead to higher performance of your script.

Answer (score 0):

First off, try and avoid multiple nested pipes to foreach-object, use foreach instead. That is, don't do

```
Get-VM | ForEach-Object {
  $VM = $_
  $_.Guest.Disks | ForEach-Object {
```

but

```
foreach($vm in Get-VM) {
  foreach($disk in $vm.Guest.disks) {
```

This makes it easy to see what objects are handled later, and there isn't need to save current object on the pipeline into a temp variable (which you do by `$VM = $_`).

Also, objects can be initialized via a hash table instead of using select-object. Like so,

```
$pctLimit = 20  # Variable sets percentage limit instead of a magic number

foreach($vm in Get-VM) {
    foreach($disk in $vm.Guest.Disks) {

        # Report object is created via hash table
        $Report = new-object PSObject -Property @{
            VM = $VM.Name
            Path = $disk.Path 
            Capacity = $disk.Capacity
            FreeSpace = $disk.FreeSpace
            ZeroDisk = ($disk.Capacity -gt 0) # NB: calculated property
        }

        if (-not $Report.ZeroDisk) { # Process only non-zero disks
            $Report.PercentageFreeSpace = [math]::Round(100*($Report.FreeSpace/$Report.Capacity))

            if($Report.PercentageFreeSpace -lt $pctLimit) {
                $report
            } else {
                # Disk had more than $pctLimit free space. Now what?
            }
        } else {
            # Disk had zero capacity. Now what?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,I give it a try but I have no output with your script

Comment: Try and add something to the Now what -sections.

Answer (score 0):

FIrst of all thanks for your help

I manage to filter with the following

```
Get-VM | ForEach-Object {
$VM = $_
$_.Guest.Disks | ForEach-Object {
$Report = "" | Select-Object -Property VM,Path,Capacity,FreeSpace,PercentageFreeSpace
$Report.VM = $VM.Name
$Report.Path = $_.Path 
$Report.Capacity = $_.Capacity
$Report.FreeSpace = $_.FreeSpace
if ($_.Capacity) {$Report.PercentageFreeSpace = [math]::Round(100*($_.FreeSpace/$_.Capacity))}
if( $_.Capacity -and $Report.PercentageFreeSpace -lt 30 ) {
    $Report
}
} 

}
```

`

Thanks,
Best regards